# HTML Jumbotron images zoomed in on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, parallax

I have an issue using jumbotron images on my website where they get more and more zoomed in as the screen size shrinks and extremely zoomed in on mobile. Is this a feature of jumbotrons? I understand the image has to shift to fill the screen but can I have that be mostly fixed except for extreme cases? I used code from w3schools to create a parallax effect on jumbotron images if that has anything to do with it. My code is below:

```
  .jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  background-image: url("./jumbo.jpg");
  color: #ffffff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 116px;
}
```

```
/* From w3schools - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp */
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("./jumbo.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 600px;

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Example usage in html:

```
<section class="jumbotron parallax image-overlay" style="background-image: url(./deadgrass.jpg);">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-auto text-center">
            <h2>Contact Me</h2>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jumbotron and parallax classes are overriding each other, you should avoid that as you might get unwanted behaviour. It is hard to say what is wrong without the image. Note that if the aspect ratio of your image is too extreme, some scaling will have to happen in order to the image cover the screen. You could use some fallback images for mobile if that's the case.